# Drush get all non-required modules

Tags: 7, drush

In Drupal, the [Module Filter](https://www.drupal.org/project/module_filter) module adds four search filters to /admin/modules:

1. Enabled
2. Disabled
3. Required
4. Unavailable

If "Required" is unchecked, the admin page will only show modules that are not dependencies of any other module. I know that `drush pm-list --status=Enabled` will show only the enabled modules, but it doesn't filter out modules that are required by other modules.

Is there a way to do the same thing using drush?

Answer (score 2):

Drush does not support such a feature, but it sounds like it would be an interesting enhancement.

Comment: Greg you have in mind implement this functionality? Do you need some help with this?

Comment: A pull request in the Drush issue queue would be most welcome. In general, though, I feel that the pm-* commands in Drush are deprecated, and that Composer should be preferred when possible.